# Split String on \b's but not on \b's between a substring

Tags: java, string

How do you split a String into words but leave certain phrases/terms intact? Right now, I have `String[] strarr = str.split("\\b");`, but I want to modify the regex parameter to accomplished what is mentioned above. **solution doesn't have to include regex**

For example, if str equals `"The city of San Francisco is truly beautiful!"` and the term is `"San Francisco"`, how do you split str so that the resulting String[] array looks as such: `["The", "city", "of", "San Francisco", "is", "truly", "beautiful!"]`?

---

After seeing @Radiodef's comment, I decided that I don't really require regex per se. If anyone can help me solve this problem, help is still much appreciated!

Comment: You can't do this accurately with a regex...regex matches patterns of characters, not names of places. This is the kind of thing which a library is for.

Comment: @Radiodef I agree that regex is not the right approach to do that, but I posted the regex answer :)

Comment: Regex has many performance issues in Java as explained here https://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2009/05/21/regex/ . You can even catch the 3 word phrase or n-word phrase in my answer. Just saying ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's a very interesting question. My approach would be to write a general method which could help in detecting any number of word phrases by returning a simple array of Strings.

[**Here is a demo**](https://ideone.com/kGh7yz)

Below is the method,

```
 String[] find(String m[], String c[], String catchStr){

    String comp = c[0];
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){

        boolean flag = false;

        //comparing if the substring matches or not
        if(comp.equals(m[i])){
            flag = true;
            for(int j=0;j<c.length;j++){
                //you can use equalsIgnoreCase() if you want to compare the string 
                //ignoring the case
                if(!m[i+j].equals(c[j])){
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        if(flag){
            list.add(catchStr);
            i = i + c.length-1;
        }else{
            list.add(m[i]);
        }

    }

    //converting result into String array
    String finalArr[] = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

    return finalArr;

}
```

You can call this function as,

```
String mainStr = "The city of San Francisco is truly beautiful!";
String catchStr = "San Francisco";
String mainStrArr[] = mainStr.split(" ");
String catchStrArr[] = catchStr.split(" ");

String finalArr[] = find(mainStrArr, catchStrArr, catchStr);
```

Comment: @javaislife I liked this solution better because it is a more general solution and unlike regular expression given by Evgeniy Dorofeev, this solution can work for any string with any number of phrases

Answer (score 1):

I know the posted answers are better but since I struggled hardly against this I'd like to share the regex answer too.

So, a posible regex approach to achieve this by using capturing groups is using this regex:

```
([A-Z][a-z]*(?:\s?[A-Z][a-z]+)*|[a-z!]+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uO8tG5/2)**

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-3]   `The`
MATCH 2
1.  [4-8]   `city`
MATCH 3
1.  [9-11]  `of`
MATCH 4
1.  [12-25] `San Francisco`
MATCH 5
1.  [26-28] `is`
MATCH 6
1.  [29-34] `truly`
MATCH 7
1.  [35-44] `beautiful!`
```

Java code

```
String line = "The city of San Francisco is truly beautiful!";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z][a-z]*(?:\\s?[A-Z][a-z]+)*|[a-z!]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Result: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, and came up with a very similar RegEx: `[A-Z]\\S+((\\s+[A-Z]\\S+)+)?|\\S+`

Answer (score 0):

If San Francisco is the only exclusion, then this works

```
    String[] a = str.split("(?<!San)\\s+(?!Francisco)");
```

the shortest solution for multiple exclusions i could find is this

```
    String str = "The city of San Francisco is truly beautiful!";
    String[] exclusions = { "San Francisco", "Los Angeles" };
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        l.add(m.group());
        for (String ex : exclusions) {
            if (str.regionMatches(m.start(), ex, 0, ex.length())) {
                l.set(l.size() - 1, ex);
                m.find();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(l);
```

Comment: This a much better approach. However your regex when you included Los   Angeles is not working

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev I was trying to fix this but in case you find it useful I came up with `\s(?=[a-z]+)` although has a bug in `of`

Comment: Thanks for your response! The multiple exclusions solution doesn't seem to be functioning properly as @Saumil Soni, but ingenious never the less. I'm very bad with regex so I was wondering how I could modify the first solution so that it would work with three-word phrases (i.e. "New York City").

Comment: second solution works only with English letters and 2 word exclusions

Answer (score 0):

Find the substring to be excluded then remove the spaces in it temporarily. Once the whole string is already split, find the substring edited previously then bring back its spaces by replacing it with the original.

```
    // let's say:
    // whole = "The city of San Francisco is truly beautiful!",
    // token = "San Francisco"

    public static String[] excludeString(String whole, String token) {

        // replaces token string "San Francisco" with "SanFrancisco"
        whole = whole.replaceAll(token, token.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));

        // splits whole string using space as delimiter, place tokens in a string array
        String[] strarr = whole.split("\\s+");

        // brings "SanFrancisco" back to "San Francisco" in strarr
        Collections.replaceAll(Arrays.asList(strarr), token.replaceAll("\\s+", ""), token);

        // returns the array of strings
        return strarr;
    }
```

Sample usage:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] arr = excludeString("The city of San Francisco is truly beautiful!", "San Francisco");
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));

    }
```

Let's say your string is: `"The city of San Francisco is truly beautiful!"`

The result will be:
`[The, city, of, San Francisco, is, truly, beautiful!]`